# Mediaplayer not opening selected file android (setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

So I have set up the following code to pick a song from internal memory and play it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
```

My onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri uriSound = data.getData();

        play(this, uriSound);
    }
}
```

and finally my play method:
     private void play(Context context, Uri uri) {

```
    MediaPlayer mip = new MediaPlayer();
    try {

        mip.setDataSource(context, uri);
        mip.prepare();
        mip.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

but when I run this I keep getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
```

I couldnt find a working solution anywhere. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Granting permission in the manifest file to read external storage fixed it!